# Symfony2, phpbrew, nginx, php 7.1 and File not found

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, phpbrew

I've been attempting to upgrade to php 7.1 using `phpbrew`, and elected to install it with nginx, as I read everywhere that it was simpler than Apache (not that simple, in my humble opinion).

As I was trying to run Symfony2 with nginx, I came across [this doc page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx), which gives a basic config for Sf2 on nginx.

I managed to configure php-fpm to serve `app_dev.php`, and every file ending in `.php` correctly. However, as soon as I go to a different URL (`/home` for instance), the nginx config breaks and I get a `File not found` error in `php-fpm`.

How do I configure the nginx virtual host to allow for everything after `app_dev.php` or `app.php` to be rewritten (as it would with `modrewrite` on apache2)?

My nginx file for reference:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /my-app {
        index web/app_dev.php;
        try_files $uri /web/app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /dist {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index depp/index.php;
        try_files $uri /depp/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/home/gabriel/.phpbrew/php/php-7.1.0/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri?$args;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a rewrite condition to catch-all the incoming requests and forward them to your front controller.

Try something like:

```
  # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
  rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

  location /my-app {
    index app.php;
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
  }

  location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
  }

 # Symfony 2 app index
   location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/home/gabriel/.phpbrew/php/php-7.1.0/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
     include fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

  # deny access to any other php files
   location ~^.*\.php(/|$) {
     deny all;
   }
```

You current configuration is a more general configuration for any `.php` script but Symfony2 and framework in general only provide a catch-all front-controller.